# Query Records in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I've been searching on how to generate daily,monthly and yearly records , but all I'm getting includes crystal reports, unfortunately I'm just a newbie and I don't know how to use crystal reports.

Is there any easy possible way to generate this report/record without using any crystal report or is it possible to implement this using queries on MS Access 2010 , Im gonna display it into a Datagrid View .

Also, Iam bit confuse in what should I use in filtering from daily,monthly,yearly records.

If possible I would like to ask an example code, I'm just new to the programming world.

Comment: As I said elsewhere, this is not a report. If you keep getting search results for Crystal Reports it's because you're using bad search keywords. All you're doing is querying a database.  You need to create a data adapter with an appropriate query, call `Fill` to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to your `DataGridView`. That's it, that's all.  As I have also said elsewhere, if you know how to query a database already (if you don't there are plenty of places to learn and you've been directed to some) then your only problem is getting the query filter right. That's what you need to search for.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service. We're here to help you with **specific** code problems or questions that you didn't find an answer to elsewhere. In addition we want to see your research/attempts in solving the problem yourself. Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593) and also [On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).